# Defining labels for recurrent neural network RNN

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm a little confused about what format to present my labels/output values for a RNN.  For RNN you define a batch of sequences as input:

```
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, sequence_size, features_size], name="X")
```

But what do I define for labels?

In my case I can provide labels for each item in the sequence as well, so I could do this:

```
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, sequence_size, labels_size], name="Y")
```

But, I assume the neural network is really only interested in what the outcome is from the sequence that's been presented to it. So is it possible to submit just a list of labels, which will correlate to result of each sequence in X:

```
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, labels_size], name="Y")
```

I'm just a little unsure how Tensorflow works behind the scenes.  Is anyone able to confirm?

Due to the way my data is formatted, it'd actually be easier to present it like this:

```
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, sequence_size, labels_size], name="Y")
```

Where I have a label for each observation in the sequence. But I just want to check that's okay?

EDIT: my question seems to be causing some confusion, and I think it's because I didn't explain the context. So let me elaborate; I'm doing weather prediction, so each day I have temperature, cloud cover, hours of sun, wind direction, pressure (etc etc etc) and using that I want to predict temperature for future two days.

So let's say I submit a sequence 10 days of weather data, for each day in the sequence do I provide the labels (temperature for future 2 days), or, do I provide it for the entire sequence, i.e. the 10-day sequence?

Comment: Depends on your task. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Would it matter on the task...? After all, all RNNs accept a sequence as input, so my question is whether it makes a difference to provide a label for each entry of the sequence, or for just the final entry in the sequence, since that's all the RNN really cares about, i.e. this sequence produces this output. If I provide for all entries of the sequence, then does Tensorflow only use the last one?

Comment: Of course. Usually there is one label per input sequence, e.g. sentiment analysis. In this case the output of the last cell only matters. But there are architectures where the result is also a sequence, e.g. encoder-decoder. In this case, labels include the output of each cell.

Comment: Aha. I'm doing weather prediction, so each day I have temperature, cloud cover, hours of sun, wind direction, pressure (etc) and using that I want to predict temperature for future two days. In my data I do have 2 labels (i.e. a sequence of 2) which corresponds to each entry in the input sequence. So should I provide the label (seq. len 2) for each separate input sequence, or each entry of the input sequence?

Comment: Re: "How Tensorflow works behind the scenes": TensorFlow does not dictate how your labels should looks like. It helps you construct the RNN and get outputs from it. Then, it is your choice how to compute the loss using these outputs and your labels. Different loss functions expect different parameters.

Comment: But if I supply outputs/labels for each entry of the sequence, how does TF (or RNNs in general) treat that differently to providing an output/label for the sequence as a whole?  Does it actually use all of those labels, or just the last one? How are they computed differently? If they are different then how to decide which to do for a given circumstance?